# How to find autoregressive coefficients of ARMA model

Tags: regression

I am searching various sources to find the method of manually calculating coefficients of Auto Regressive Moving Average model. The following is the text I found in a book. My question is how a<sub>1</sub> and a<sub>2</sub> are found. Can any one please help.

"Higher-order autoregressive models include more lagged y<sub>t</sub>  terms as predictors. For example, the second-order autoregressive model, AR(2), is given by
$$
y_{t}+a_{1}y_{t-1}+a_{2}y_{t-2}=e_{t}
$$
where a<sub>1</sub> , a<sub>2</sub> are the autoregressive coefficients on lags 1 and 2."

Comment: Did you try to use maximum likelihood method?

Comment: Yes. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using maximum likelihood method.